# Using firebase with modular javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a simple website with an `index.html`, and a script tag linked to a `main.js` file. The tag is of type `module`. I don't use any libraries or anything like that. I have tried solutions online, but they all use some kind of bundler, and it doesn't seem to work without them. I created my app with `firebase init hosting`.

When i try importing firebase with `import firebase from 'firebase'` or `import * as firebase from 'firebase'`, i get the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"`.

What should i do here? This is my first time using firebase with javascript modules.

Firebase says to use script tags to access firebase, but i cannot do that.

Comment: where in the docs is it saying do that?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i saw  it in a firecast episode on youtube. I couldnt find reference other places.

Comment: rtm: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize

Answer (score 0):

`import .. from 'firebase'` will cause JavaScript to look in the node_modules folder. If I understand you correctly, you don't have one and you don't want one either.

Firebase doesn't need to be included like that, you can also just add scripts to the bottom of your body in your html like this:

```html
<script src="/__/firebase/5.11.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

If hosting is the only thing you want this should do it, even without a config object. Otherwise check this out:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: I dont have a problem with using node modules, i just couldnt get them to work. I know i can use the script tags like that, but when working with javascript modules you cant acccess them (could probably do it with some ugly window property assignments, but i would favor not doing that)

Comment: In that case, read up on node.js. Did you install firebase with `npm i -S firebase`? Otherwise the node module doesn't actually exist. Here is reference for node.js: https://nodejs.org/en/. Help for firebase with node.js is on the same site I sent you in the post above, just click on the 'Node.js app' tab on for instance step 3.

Comment: I have used node a lot, but never with websites and html pages and stuff. Thanks for the tip, ill try it and message back if there is a problem.